# Docpad can not see my collections within helper

Tags: collections, coffeescript, helper, docpad

I have docpad(v6.64.0), 1 layout file and 1 document at hand to try docpad, but i always get null in my document file.

document file- *index.html.eco*:

```
<% for m in @getArchivePages().toJSON(): %>
 ......
<% end %>
```

docpad.coffee:

```
....
templateData:
   getArchivePages: ->
     @getCollection("pages")

collections:
  pages: ->
    @getCollection("html").findAllLive({layout: "post"}, [{date: -1}])
```

file layout:

- root

  - docpad.coffee
  - src

    - documents

      - index.html.eco

The `getArchivePages` helper always return `null`.
please help me to figure it out. thanks.

Comment: It seems the `@` for this is not the same in document context and helper context. So, the `getCollection` is different in the helper function. But i am not very sure.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem -- I'm just trying to work through the beginner's Guide and the issue is occurring on the example that they are providing in the ADDING A MENU LISTING FOR OUR PAGES section.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to use e.g. @getCollection("pages") from within the document (.eco) files directly, and not have the second stage of declaring templateData too.